# Android Navigation Drawer sometimes doesn't appear, but screen dims

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My navigation drawer sometimes does not appear, the toggle button turns into an arrow pointing left and the screen dims, but the fragments and layout don't appear.

I can't reliably replicate this issue and it happens rarely, randomly, and didn't see anything in my searches about it. So maybe this is a known issue or maybe others are having the same thing.

Comment: The screen dimming is a sign that the drawer is opened. Do you perhaps open it at the start of your activity?

Comment: This can happen if you have an incorrect z-ordering of the child Views in your DrawerLayout. Make sure the drawer View is listed last in the layout xml, and that you're not adding Views to the DrawerLayout during runtime that would appear on top of it.

Comment: @user3249477 I didn't make it clear, I do the required actions to open the drawer manually, with gestures. then the screen dims but nothing shows